# How can I get something to crumble instead of explode while using the cell Fracture addon?

Tags: animation, add-on, physics, rigid-body-simulation

[image]I am making an earthquake and I use the cell fracture addon to make my buildings separate pieces but instead of the buildings crumpling like they should, they explode. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure collision margins of the rigid bodies are set to zero, and the physics iterations are high enough to handle whatever simulation you run... also increase the physics time step to a higher value.... it's also sometimes useful to check the "start disabled" checkbox in the rigid bodies tab... this should stop the objects moving until a collision occurs